# How to change rendering of div order in a field?

Tags: entities

It appears that the module [label help](https://www.drupal.org/project/label_help) is not compatible with Date fields. It allows you to enter text, but it does not display.

I found out that in the div with class description should be above div id edit-field-geboortedatum-und-0-value instead of below

How to achieve this? Should I change a weight key in something?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use $form['#after_build'] to modify a form. Put below element at the end of your hook_form function.

```
$form['#after_build'][] = 'FORM_NAME_after_build'; //Calls function
```

After build function to change the position of DIV

```
function FORM_NAME_after_build($form, $form_state) {
  drupal_add_js('jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#edit-field-geboortedatum-und-0-value").insertAfter($(".description"));
  });', array('type' => 'inline', 'scope' => 'footer', 'weight' => 5));

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: works perfectly!